# Confusion about unit testing frameworks?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I get the concept of unit testing and TDD on a whole.

However, I'm still a little confused on what exactly unit testing frameworks are. Whenever I read about unit testing, it's usually an explanation of what it is, followed by "oh here are the frameworks for this language, i.e JUnit".

But what does that really mean? Are framework just a sort of testing library that allows programmers to write simpler/efficient unit tests?

Also, what are the benefits of using a framework? As I understand it, unit testing is done on small chunks of code at a time, i.e a method. However, I could individually write a test for a method without using a unit testing framework. Is it maybe for standardization of testing practices?

I'm just very new to testing and unit-testing, clarification on some basic concepts would be great.

Comment: What do you expect to write for all your methods? Dozens of main methods, one for each method? Or one main method, calling dozens of test methods... Since the first answer is obviously bullshit, you could go in the second direction, thus effectively starting to write your own unit test framework... And this is, why we have unit testing frameworks so that we don't need to write a very primitive one from scratch every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a broad question, but I think there are certain thoughts that could count as as facts for an answer:

- When 5, 10, 100, ... people go forward to "work" with the same idea/concept (for example unit testing) then, most likely, certain patterns respectively *best practices* will evolve. People have ideas, and by trial and error they find out which of those ideas are helpful and which are not.
- Then people start to communicate their ideas, and those "commonly used" patterns undergo discussions and get further refined.
- And sooner or later, people start thinking "I am doing the same task over and over again; I should write a program for me to do that".

And that is how frameworks come into existence: they are **tools** to support certain aspects of a specific activity.

Let's give an example: using a framework like JUnit, I can completely focus on writing test cases. I don't need to worry about accumulation of failure statistics; I don't need to worry how to make sure that really *all* my tests are executed when I want that to happen.

I simply understand how to use the JUnit framework; and I know how to **further** utilize JUnit test cases in conjunction with *build* systems such as gradle or maven - in order to have all my unit tests executed automatically; each time I push a commit into my source code management system for example.

Of course you can re-invent the wheel here; and implement all of that yourself. But that is just a waste of time. It is like saying: "I want to move my crop to the market - let's start by building the truck myself". No. You rent or buy a pre-build truck; and you use that to do what you *actually* want to do (move things around).